# Minimizing the largest eigenvalue of random matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix with entries $A_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N} (0,1)$, all independent except for the symmetry condition.

Consider the following minimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\inf \limits_{u \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum u_i = 0 }\{  \ \lambda_{max}( A - \text{Diag}(u))\} 
\end{equation}

where $\lambda_{max}(\cdot)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue and $\text{D}(v)$ is the diagonal matrix having the vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as entries.

I don't want to necessarily find the optimal value of this problem. It would suffice to find a vector $u$ that achieves a smaller value than the trivial vector $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, for large $n$.

**Question**: How would one find a vector $u$, with $\sum_i u_i = 0 $ (possibly random and dependent on $A$), that achives a smaller value than the zero vector asymptotically for large $n$ with high probability? For the zero vector the value is $\lambda_{max}(A)$ for which it is know that $\lambda_{max}(A) = \Theta( 2 n^{3/2}) $.

Is there existing literature on this problem? What methods might one use?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want that $\sum u_i = 0$?

Comment: The mentioned problem can be viewed as an upper bound to the problem of maximizing $x^t A x$ over the hypercube.

Comment: I would like to find a vector such that the value is smaller than the value attained by the zero vector with high probability for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I think that due to the $\Sigma u_i = 0$ constraint and the convexity of $\lambda_{max}$, Jensen's inequality is going against you.

Comment: (continued)  i.e., on average (in expectation). Unless you make specific use of a particular instantiation of $A$, in which case you can get an improvement a.s. for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Could you maybe add the details of your comments as an answer? I would also be interested in the average case i.e., in expectation as you mentioned.

Comment: I'll defer to someone else to make rigorous/fix up, if true. Basically a rigorized version of the following: Whatever $u$ we come up with, only accounting for $n$, but not specific instantiation of $A$, should do no better or worse on average than any reordering of the elements of $u$. So $\lambda_{max}(A) = \lambda_{max}(E(A-diag(u))) \le E(\lambda_{max}(A-diag(u)))$ by Jensen's Inequality.

Comment: How is $\lambda_{\max}(A) = \lambda_{\max}(E(A-\mathrm{diag}(u))$? Taking $u = 0$ would imply $\lambda_{\max}(A) = \lambda_{\max}(E(A)) = 0$, which is not true.

Comment: @smapers That was not clearly written out. The expectation is (sort of?) conditional on the value of A.  I.e., randomly reordering elements of u for a fixed $A$. Anyhow, this is not a rigorous argument, rather, a germ of an idea, and perhaps it is wrong. That is why I did not submit it as an answer.

Comment: Oh I see now. That's a nice argument. It indeed would make more sense to let $u$ depend on the specific instance $A$.

Comment: @smapers I have now fixed up the argument (no longer directly using Jensen's inequality to exploit the convexity) and submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a given instantiation of $A$, the globally optimal value of $u$ can be found as the solution of a convex Linear Semidefinite Programming (SDP) problem using a standard solver such as Mosek. This optimum achieves a better objective value than $u = 0$ a.s. for $n \ge 2$.

Now assume, I believe as intended, that $u$ must be specified only with knowledge of $n$, but not with knowledge of a specific instantiation of $A$.

By convexity of $\lambda_{max}$ of a real symmetric matrix, 
$$\lambda_{max}(A) \le \frac{1}{2}\lambda_{max}(A-\text{diag}(u)) + \frac{1}{2}\lambda_{max}(A-\text{diag}(-u))$$

Taking expectation of both sides,
$$E(\lambda_{max}(A)) \le \frac{1}{2}E(\lambda_{max}(A-\text{diag}(u))) + \frac{1}{2}E(\lambda_{max}(A-\text{diag}(-u)))$$

Because $u$ was chosen without knowledge of the instantiation of $A$, and all elements of $A$ are symmetrically distributed about zero, it must be the case that 
$$E(\lambda_{max}(A-\text{diag}(-u))) =E(\lambda_{max}(A-\text{diag}(u)))$$

and therefore
$$E(\lambda_{max}(A)) \le E(\lambda_{max}(A-\text{diag}(u)))$$

So such a $u$ can do no better on average than $u = 0$.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain the downvote?